# Kinetic eclipse indexer problem

Tags: ros-kinetic, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 and Kinetic, the CDT indexer in Eclipse no longer indexes my files properly (tried on 3 different machines and Eclipse Mars, Luna, Neon). The #include are resolved but the files are not indexed. I can Ctrl+click on the include declaration and it takes me to the file, but none of the classes/functions are indexed, which means that in my cpp/h files these are showing up in red (eclipse says the declaration cannot be resolved) and autocompletion breaks.
catkin_make shows no errors and the code runs without any problems. I have not run into this problem in previous versions of Ubuntu/ROS.
Has anyone else experienced this? How did you resolve it if you did?
I have followed the instructions on the wiki without any luck: http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Eclipse

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240639/kinetic-eclipse-indexer-problem/) by [mgerdzhev](https://answers.ros.org/users/20158/mgerdzhev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-07-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gabehein](https://answers.ros.org/users/22175/gabehein/) on 2016-08-13**:
I am having this exact problem. Only with certain, larger, projects though. Seems like it might be a size issue but the errors that eclipse reports during the indexing process, 'failed to parse file', are pretty useless.

**Comment by [roboflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27845/roboflyer/) on 2016-08-27**:
Same problem here. I did find someting odd, in providers, if I choose  "CDT User Setting Entries" and nothing else, the internal project files are indexed but not other libraries. If I chose "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings", it's the other way around. Either way, lots of unresolved references!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I resolved the problem by updating cdt to the current nightly build. You can install the build by opening the "Install New Software Dialog" (Help -> Install New Software) and use http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/master/nightly/ as the download source. As it seems the cdt indexer crashes internally if you use a version < 9.1. I tested it with Java 9, Eclipse Neon, and ROS Kinetic.

Bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497524

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Kuhner](https://answers.ros.org/users/608/daniel-kuhner/) with karma: 44 on 2016-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1